# DataGrid is not binding in WPF

Tags: wpf

I am trying to bind DataGrid using MVVM approach in WPF, model is getting values but nothing is showing in DataGrid 
Following is my code

```
 public class TalleyEditorGrid : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    #region Properties
    private string _Quantity;
    private string _Ft;
    private string _Inch;
    private string _Comment;

    public string Quantity { get { return _Quantity; } set { _Quantity = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Quantity"); } }
    public string Ft { get { return _Ft; } set { _Ft = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Ft"); } }
    public string Inch { get { return _Inch; } set { _Inch = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Inch"); } }
    public string Comment { get { return _Comment; } set { _Comment = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Comment"); } }
    #endregion

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName) { PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName)); }
}
```

In my xaml.cs

```
 private ObservableCollection<TalleyEditorGrid> _TalleyEditorGrid = new ObservableCollection<TalleyEditorGrid>();    
    public ObservableCollection<TalleyEditorGrid> TalleyEditorCol
    {
        get { return _TalleyEditorGrid; } 
    }
```

On button click I am filling this collection

```
  _TalleyEditorGrid.Add(new TalleyEditorGrid() { Quantity = Q, Ft = FT, Inch = In, Comment = Comment});
```

Xaml as follows

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="TalleyEditor" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TalleyEditorCol}"  AutoGenerateColumns="True" Visibility="Collapsed" 
              CanUserAddRows="False"
              HorizontalGridLinesBrush="{x:Null}" 
              VerticalGridLinesBrush="Silver" 
              Background="White"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              SelectionUnit="FullRow"
              CanUserReorderColumns="True"
              CanUserSortColumns="True"  DataGridCell.GotFocus="TalleyEditor_GotFocus" 
              RowHeaderWidth="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" RowHeight="17" ColumnHeaderHeight="21" PreviewKeyDown="TalleyEditor_PreviewKeyDown" LostFocus="TalleyEditor_LostFocus" CellEditEnding="myDG_CellEditEnding">
```

Comment: this binding `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TalleyEditorCol}"` needs A DataContext set to TalleyEditorGrid. how do you set DataContext in your view?

Comment: Your property isn't raising `NotifyPropertyChanged` when the collection changes.  You should know that a *better* way to handle this is to make your collections read-only, so the instance never changes, then when you want to update the collection, `.Clear` it, and `.Add` the new values.  This works much better with the way data binding is implemented in WPF.

Comment: I'm also not seeing you set a binding on `ItemsSource` on your `DataGrid`.

Comment: @ASh can you help me how to do that?

Comment: @BradleyUffner it is there ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TalleyEditorCol}"

Comment: @ASh still not happening what to do in xaml?

Comment: @C.jacking, I misread part of code. add `DataContext = this;` after InitializeComponent(). then Window with `TalleyEditorCol` will become its own DataContext and `Path=TalleyEditorCol` will be resolved

Comment: @ASh don't know why but still not getting value in datagrid, pls note I am not adding value to _TalleyEditorGrid in MainWindow.xaml.cs

Comment: By using DataContext = this; after adding values to collection is working but when i put that Datagrid in            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate> it is not getting values

Comment: @C.jacking: Did you try my suggestion or what happened?

Comment: @mm8 yes using DataContext = this; worked

Comment: @mm8 along with changes as follows ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TalleyEditorCol,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:OrderEntry}}}"

Comment: OrderEntry is not a visual ancestor. Anyway, why don't you accept my answer if your issue has been solved?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `DataContext` of the window to itself:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

Or set the `DataContext` of the `DataGrid`:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    TalleyEditor.DataContext = this;
}
```

If you put the `DataGrid` inside another `DataGrid`, you need to use a `{RelativeSource}` to be able to bind to a property of the parent window:

```
<DataGrid ... ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TalleyEditorCol, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}">

</DataGrid>
```

Comment: TalleyEditor is inside cell of another datagrid so not accessible using TalleyEditor.DataContext = this;

Comment: What about my second suggestion then...?